# Using condition expression to choose lambda expression

Tags: c#

I want to use condition expression to choose lambda expression, like that:

```
xxxx.UsingFactory(
hasProofing? ( ()=>new ProofingA() ) : ( () => new ProofingB() )
);
```

But, it show me errors. So, if I want to do this thing, How should I do.

Error Detail:

> no implicit conversion between 'lambda expression' and 'lambda
>   expression'

Comment: *show me errors* .. It is very helpful if you state those errors. Also, show the signature of the `UsingFactory`, what does it accept as parameters ? Do `ProofingA` and `ProofingB` inherit from the same object ?

Comment: implement from the same interface

Comment: Also, what `xxx.UsingFactory()` takes as parameter? may be it does not take an Action without parameters? try `x=>new ProfingA()`

Comment: You have to explicitly cast your lambdas. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5490095) question, or maybe [these](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8506733) [ones](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11309557)

Comment: @v11 And does your method accept `Func<iThatComonInterface>` or accepts what exactly ? Just an `Action` ?

Comment: @user3185569 I think just action,  and I have solved this problem via using if /else to choose return new proofingA() or proofingB()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly cast at least one of the lambdas. For example, if it's just a `Action`, then you could use the following:

```
xxxx.UsingFactory(
    hasProofing ? (Action)(() => new ProofingA()) : () => new ProofingB()
);
```